# Identifier in DTO when POSTing in Web API?

Tags: api, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API and I am using DTOs to abstract the underlying data model from the client. I have [at the moment] one DTO per controller. This DTO in all cases contains the database id of the data being passed about. On a GET, PUT, DELETE this makes sense (although DELETE and GET just use the id and not the DTO on the request obviously), but on the POST it doesn't make sense as the new data being added has no id yet.

In other words I am asking the client to pass to the API a structure that includes an Id field but I will ignore the content of that Id field. Is this acceptable or should I create an UpdateDTO and a RetrieveDto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the data structure you have. Make the Id field optional. If the value of Id is set when a POST comes in, return an error.